# Apply foreground effect to the node child of a mindmap or background to the arm of the parent node

Tags: nodes, backgrounds, mindmaps

I need the node child's "Tree" arm not to overlap the node child "BIRD'S TO ...". I've been trying to load the library backgrouns and use "on backaground layer" in the options for the child "Tree" but that did not trigger changes.

Here my MWE and image of problem:

```
   \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=35cm,paperheight=39cm,left=2cm,top=2cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
    \centering
    \tikzset{every node/.style={text width=2cm,minimum size=5cm}}
 \node [concept, text=blue!50!black!10,align=center] at (0,0) 
      {\Huge Floor} 
child [concept color=blue!50, grow=-90,level distance=412]
    {node [concept] {\Huge Sky}
child [concept color=black!20!yellow!20!red!30!blue!10!green!30,grow=240,level distance=210]
    {node [scale=0.9,concept] {\Huge BIRD'S TO..}}
child [concept color=black!20!yellow!20!red!30!blue!10!green!30,grow=240,level distance=410]
    {node [scale=0.9,concept] {\Huge Tree.}}
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: "Birds To ..." is obfuscated]

Comment: Just for clarification: the position of the bubbles should be the same but "BIRD'S TO ..." should overlay the connecting line?

Comment: Hi @samcarter, what you asked is exactly what I want, but this must be something totally appropriate to nodes or mindmaps, I do not want improvisations.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! What I don't yet understand: why not make "birds to" a child of "sky" and "tree" a child of "birds to"?

Comment: Yes, I have already used his advice and it really works to get the desired effect, but this changes who is the parent and I need for better mindmap purposes so the parent remains Sky.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to place the "bird" node on top of the finished mindmap:

```
   \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=35cm,paperheight=39cm,left=2cm,top=2cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
    \centering
    \tikzset{every node/.style={text width=2cm,minimum size=5cm}}
 \node [concept, text=blue!50!black!10,align=center] at (0,0) 
      {\Huge Floor} 
child [concept color=blue!50, grow=-90,level distance=412]
    {node [concept] (sky) {\Huge Sky}
child [concept color=black!20!yellow!20!red!30!blue!10!green!30,grow=240,level distance=412]
%    {node [scale=0.9,concept] {\Huge BIRD'S TO..}}
%child [concept color=black!20!yellow!20!red!30!blue!10!green!30,grow=240,level distance=410]
    {node [scale=0.9,concept] (tree) {\Huge Tree.}}
    }
;


\node [extra concept,text width=4.5cm,minimum size=4.5cm,fill=black!20!yellow!20!red!30!blue!10!green!30,draw=black!20!yellow!20!red!30!blue!10!green!30, text=black] at ($(tree)!0.5!(sky)$) {\huge BIRD'S TO..};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the @samcarter solution, I created a new MWE containing only one change in relation to the use of library backgrounds and scopes so that the child Tree node refers to the parent node Sky but in the background and with a decrease in the minimum size. This way also, create multiple descendants of node childs without obfuscating the text of the previous child node.

[image: my inspiration about sample of the @samcarter]

```
   \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=35cm,paperheight=39cm,left=2cm,top=2cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,backgrounds}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
    \centering
    \tikzset{every node/.style={text width=2cm,minimum size=5cm}}
 \node [concept, text=blue!50!black!10,align=center] at (0,0) 
      {\Huge Floor} 
child [concept color=blue!50, grow=-90,level distance=412,on background layer]
    {node [concept] (sky) {\Huge Sky}
child [concept color=black!20!yellow!20!red!30!blue!10!green!30,grow=240,level distance=210]
    {node [scale=0.9,concept] {\Huge BIRD'S TO..}}};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node [minimum size=3cm] at (sky) {}
child [concept color=black!20!yellow!20!red!30!blue!10!green!30,grow=240,level distance=410]
    {node [scale=0.9,concept] {\Huge Tree.}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```